# Truncated unicode escape trying to run a Python script from the command line

Tags: python

Whenever I access a cmd window and after type in 'python' and then try to access a python file, I get the error,

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape.
```

I am really puzzled by this; I try to run a python file by typing the file path inside of quotations, and I have also tried putting the r before the path. I have also tried doubling the slashes, but that only results in the window regurgitating the path.

Comment: What's the encoding of the python file?

Comment: can you show us the code that triggers the error?

Comment: The problem here is with the contents of the file, not how you're dealing with it from your command prompt; in particular, it appears not to use the character encoding the interpreter expects. This can be an editor-configuration issue; a missing hint inside the source; or a combination of the two (adding a hint specifying UTF-8 won't help if the actual encoding is something else, for obvious reasons).

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you. My code is a simple test command of the print('hello') and such.

Answer (score 0):

add a "r" in front of path, example:

```
f = open(r"C:\Users\leok9\my_file.txt")
```